# I can't do login using $_SESSION on PHP

Tags: php, session, xampp

I'm trying to make a website with XAMP using PHP, MySQL and Bootstrap. I'm beginner in PHP so I take this code on website of developers and when I tried to run on localhost I typed my credentials and the index.php did a refresh only, not show nothing errors, just refresh. I researched on web for 5 days and nothing, here's my code:

index.php

```
<?php session_start(); ?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Signin Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">

      <form class="form-signin" action="validacao.php" method="post">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
        <label for="txUsuario" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        <input type="text"  name="usuario" id="txUsuario" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required autofocus>
        <label for="inputPassword" name="senha" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
          </label>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
      </form>

    </div> <!-- /container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

validacao.php

```
<?php

  // Verifica se houve POST e se o usuário ou a senha é(são) vazio(s)
  if (!empty($_POST) AND (empty($_POST['usuario']) OR empty($_POST['senha']))) {
      header("Location: index.php"); exit;
  }

  // Tenta se conectar ao servidor MySQL
  mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or trigger_error(mysql_error());
  // Tenta se conectar a um banco de dados MySQL
  mysql_select_db('wda_crud') or trigger_error(mysql_error());

  $usuario = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['usuario']);
  $senha = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['senha']);

  // Validação do usuário/senha digitados
  $sql = "SELECT `id`, `nome`, `nivel` FROM `usuarios` WHERE (`usuario` = '".$usuario ."') AND (`senha` = '".$senha ."') AND (`ativo` = 1) LIMIT 1";
  $query = mysql_query($sql);
  if (mysql_num_rows($query) != 1) {
      // Mensagem de erro quando os dados são inválidos e/ou o usuário não foi encontrado
      echo "Login inválido!"; exit;
  } else {
      // Salva os dados encontrados na variável $resultado
      $resultado = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

      // Se a sessão não existir, inicia uma
      if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

      // Salva os dados encontrados na sessão
      $_SESSION['UsuarioID'] = $resultado['id'];
      $_SESSION['UsuarioNome'] = $resultado['nome'];
      $_SESSION['UsuarioNivel'] = $resultado['nivel'];

      // Redireciona o visitante
      header("Location: site.php"); exit;
  }

  ?>
```

site.php

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Dashboard Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse fixed-top bg-inverse">
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right hidden-lg-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><?php echo $_SESSION['UsuarioNome']; ?></a>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Settings</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Profile</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Help</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <nav class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 hidden-xs-down bg-faded sidebar">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Overview <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Reports</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Analytics</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Export</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav item</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav item again</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">One more nav</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Another nav item</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav item again</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">One more nav</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Another nav item</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        <main class="col-sm-9 offset-sm-3 col-md-10 offset-md-2 pt-3">
          <h1>Dashboard</h1>

          <section class="row text-center placeholders">
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
              <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAAJ12AAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=" width="200" height="200" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
              <h4>Label</h4>
              <div class="text-muted">Something else</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
              <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAADcgwAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=" width="200" height="200" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
              <h4>Label</h4>
              <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
              <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAAJ12AAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=" width="200" height="200" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
              <h4>Label</h4>
              <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
              <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAADcgwAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=" width="200" height="200" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
              <h4>Label</h4>
              <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
            </div>
          </section>

          <h2>Section title</h2>
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>#</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,001</td>
                  <td>Lorem</td>
                  <td>ipsum</td>
                  <td>dolor</td>
                  <td>sit</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,002</td>
                  <td>amet</td>
                  <td>consectetur</td>
                  <td>adipiscing</td>
                  <td>elit</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,003</td>
                  <td>Integer</td>
                  <td>nec</td>
                  <td>odio</td>
                  <td>Praesent</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,003</td>
                  <td>libero</td>
                  <td>Sed</td>
                  <td>cursus</td>
                  <td>ante</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,004</td>
                  <td>dapibus</td>
                  <td>diam</td>
                  <td>Sed</td>
                  <td>nisi</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,005</td>
                  <td>Nulla</td>
                  <td>quis</td>
                  <td>sem</td>
                  <td>at</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,006</td>
                  <td>nibh</td>
                  <td>elementum</td>
                  <td>imperdiet</td>
                  <td>Duis</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,007</td>
                  <td>sagittis</td>
                  <td>ipsum</td>
                  <td>Praesent</td>
                  <td>mauris</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,008</td>
                  <td>Fusce</td>
                  <td>nec</td>
                  <td>tellus</td>
                  <td>sed</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,009</td>
                  <td>augue</td>
                  <td>semper</td>
                  <td>porta</td>
                  <td>Mauris</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,010</td>
                  <td>massa</td>
                  <td>Vestibulum</td>
                  <td>lacinia</td>
                  <td>arcu</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,011</td>
                  <td>eget</td>
                  <td>nulla</td>
                  <td>Class</td>
                  <td>aptent</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,012</td>
                  <td>taciti</td>
                  <td>sociosqu</td>
                  <td>ad</td>
                  <td>litora</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,013</td>
                  <td>torquent</td>
                  <td>per</td>
                  <td>conubia</td>
                  <td>nostra</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,014</td>
                  <td>per</td>
                  <td>inceptos</td>
                  <td>himenaeos</td>
                  <td>Curabitur</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,015</td>
                  <td>sodales</td>
                  <td>ligula</td>
                  <td>in</td>
                  <td>libero</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Someone can tell me what is the error? It can be the XAMP?

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: `session_start()` needs to be the first thing you do on every page, namely `validacao.php`

Comment: @RiggsFolly PHP doesn't have any errors, console show nothing, I think the problem is the connection with SQL.@Darren I put `session_start();` in the first line on `validacao.php` and the prolem still occurs.

Comment: Did you fix the `name` attribute on the password field? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42545462/2310830

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error in this line

There is no name field in

```
   <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
```

you have put name field in label

```
    <label for="inputPassword" name="senha" class="sr-only">Password</label>
```

change this two lines to

```
    <input type="password" name="senha" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>

    <label for="inputPassword"  class="sr-only">Password</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<input...>` tags must have a `name=` attribute or they will not be sent from the HTML form to the PHP script by the browser.

So add a `name=` attribute to this `<input>`

```
<input type="password" name="senha" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I am guessing its just a typo because you have a `name="senha"` attribute in the `<label>` and that is not necessary.

```
<label for="inputPassword" name="senha" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        can be removed     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

> Note: You should always code your `session_start();` at the top of your scripts right after the first `<?php`

Comment: Thank you! I solved the problem with your answer and the answer above.